# Using LINQ to extract list

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I tried extracting the list using this piece of code. If I do it like this, Vertices will always parse just the first Point and skip all the remaining ones. (Vertices.Count == 1)

```
    Lines = xdoc.Descendants("LineEntity")
                 .Select(line => new LineEntity
                 {
                     Id = (long)line.Element("Id"),
                     Name = (string)line.Element("Name"),
                     ConductorMaterial = (string)line.Element("ConductorMaterial"),
                     IsUnderground = (bool)line.Element("IsUnderground"),
                     R = (float)line.Element("R"),
                     FirstEnd = (long)line.Element("FirstEnd"),
                     SecondEnd = (long)line.Element("SecondEnd"),
                     LineType = (string)line.Element("LineType"),
                     ThermalConstantHeat = (long)line.Element("ThermalConstantHeat"),
                     Vertices = line.Descendants("Vertices")
                     .Select(p => new Point3D
                     {
                         X = (double)p.Element("Point").Element("X"),
                         Y = (double)p.Element("Point").Element("Y"),
                         Z = 1
                     }).ToList()
                 }).ToList();
```

The XML file that I want to parse looks like this

[image: XML code]

Comment: Could you replace the image of the xml, with the actual xml as text?

Comment: Out of curisity, why do you have .Value for the x and y point parts but not the others?

Comment: I see for float in R you don't parse, but you do for double in X and Y, why? Try casting just like you do for float without parsing and doing the .Value, will it work?

Comment: @Mocas tried it and edited the code, still parses just the first values in Point.

Comment: @Marco its a few thousand lines

Comment: A reproducible subset is enough. Just like the one in the image actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get `Point` from `Vertices`

```
Vertices = line.Descendants("Vertices")
               .Elements("Point")
               .Select(p => new Point3D
                 {
                     X = (double)p.Element("X"),
                     Y = (double)p.Element("Y"),
                     Z = 1
                 })
```

```
Lines = xdoc.Descendants("LineEntity")
             .Select(line => new LineEntity
             {
                 Id = (long)line.Element("Id"),
                 Name = (string)line.Element("Name"),
                 ConductorMaterial = (string)line.Element("ConductorMaterial"),
                 IsUnderground = (bool)line.Element("IsUnderground"),
                 R = (float)line.Element("R"),
                 FirstEnd = (long)line.Element("FirstEnd"),
                 SecondEnd = (long)line.Element("SecondEnd"),
                 LineType = (string)line.Element("LineType"),
                 ThermalConstantHeat = (long)line.Element("ThermalConstantHeat"),
                 Vertices = line.Descendants("Vertices").Elements("Point")
                 .Select(p => new Point3D
                 {
                     X = (double)p.Element("X"),
                     Y = (double)p.Element("Y"),
                     Z = 1
                 }).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just deserialize document, no need to parse it manually:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]//here comes name of your top-level xml element, ie root
public class RootDoc
{
    public List<LineEntity> Lines { get; set; }
}
public class LineEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    [XmlArrayItem("Point")]
    public List<Point3D> Vertices { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ParseTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Repro()
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("in.xml"));
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootDoc));

        var reader = xdoc.CreateReader();
        var parsed = (RootDoc)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        
        parsed.Lines.ForEach(x=> x.Vertices.ForEach(y=> y.Z = 1)); //setting Z value like in your example.
        var lines = parsed.Lines;
    }
}
```

Example xml:

```
<root>
  <Lines>
    <LineEntity>
      <Id>123</Id>
      <Name>nn</Name>
      <Vertices>
        <Point>
          <X>123.123</X>
          <Y>234.234</Y>
        </Point>
      </Vertices>
    </LineEntity>
  </Lines>
</root>
```

**PS**

you don't have custom mapping logic of your fields, so do not overcomplicate standard procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this, or along this lines
Not exactly sure how it is, but you get the idea.

```
        Lines = xdoc.Descendants("LineEntity")
                 .Select(line => new LineEntity
                 {
                     Id = (long)line.Element("Id"),
                     Name = (string)line.Element("Name"),
                     ConductorMaterial = (string)line.Element("ConductorMaterial"),
                     IsUnderground = (bool)line.Element("IsUnderground"),
                     R = (float)line.Element("R"),
                     FirstEnd = (long)line.Element("FirstEnd"),
                     SecondEnd = (long)line.Element("SecondEnd"),
                     LineType = (string)line.Element("LineType"),
                     ThermalConstantHeat = (long)line.Element("ThermalConstantHeat"),
                     Vertices = line.Descendants("Vertices")
                     .Select(v =>
                     {
                         return v.Descendants("Ponit").Select(p =>
                         {
                             new new Point3D
                             {
                                 X = (double).Element("X"),
                                 Y = (double).Element("Y"),
                                 Z = 1
                             }
                         }
                      }).ToList()
                 }).ToList();
```